# How to run scala App on AWS using boxfuse

Tags: cloudcaptain

Boxfuse is claiming to be a wrapper for everything that runs on JVM. Cannot find in the docs how to wrap a scala application.

Comment: How is your Scala app packaged? (Executable) Jar, .war, some other format?

Answer (score 1):

With Boxfuse you can run Scala applications either as [executables jars](https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/jar) or [Tomcat wars](https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/tomcat). Boxfuse also comes with native deep integration and optimization for [Play applications](https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/play) written in either Scala or Java.